# unable to access dns from a kubernetes pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes master and node setup in two centos VMs on my Win 10.
I used flannel for CNI and deployed ambassador as an API gateway.
As the ambassador routes did not work, I analysed further to understand that the DNS (ip-10.96.0.10) is not accessible from busybox pod which means that none of the service names can be accessed. Could I get any suggestion please.

Comment: Issue might be with the internal network setup between your VMs , take a look at this article - http://www.brianlinkletter.com/how-to-use-virtualbox-to-emulate-a-network/ , it explains how you can create an internal network between VMs( assuming they are Virtual Box)

Comment: I will read thru this article. Thanks for the time. A point to notice is that I use HOST ONLY NETWORK of VirtualBox. could that be a problem?

Comment: So if you have read [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) article on setting up Kubernetes cluster , it suggests that your nodes must be able to communicate to each other , either on public or private network. So it is upto you how you do that communication. When I had done this setup , I used the bridged mode on my VMs so they could communicate to each other using underlying IP provided by DHCP , you can give this a try if that works for you

Comment: [root@k8s-master sony]# kubectl exec ambassador-7ddbcf6557-hgs95 -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.91.59.137
nameserver 10.165.108.1
nameserver 10.165.108.2
search <org domain>

Comment: the observation is - kube-dns service ip is not reachable from pods (especially from pods on minion nodes) I tried the access from a -n kube-system pod from master node and kube-dns cluster ip was accessible over nc command. But when I tried nslookup kubernetes it failed.

Comment: Hello Sonny, could you show me cluster components, every pods in every namespaces and services ?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** You should use newest version of Flannel.

Flannel does not setup service IPs but kube-proxy does, you should look at kube-proxy on your nodes and ensure they are not reporting errors.
I'd suggest taking a look at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#tabs-pod-install-4 and ensure you have met the requirements stated there.

Similar issue but with Calico plugin you can find here: https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/1798

**2.** Check if you have open port 8285, flannel uses UDP port 8285 for sending encapsulated IP packets. Make sure to enable this traffic to pass between the hosts.

**3.** Ambassador includes an integrated diagnostics service to help with troubleshooting, this may be useful for you. By default, this is not exposed to the Internet. To view it, we'll need to get the name of one of the Ambassador pods:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                          READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ambassador-3655608000-43x86   1/1       Running   0          2m
ambassador-3655608000-w63zf   1/1       Running   0          2m
```

Forwarding local port 8877 to one of the pods:

```
kubectl port-forward ambassador-3655608000-43x86 8877
```

will then let us view the diagnostics at http://localhost:8877/ambassador/v0/diag/.

First spot should solve your problem, if not, try remainings.
I hope this helps.

Comment: I will try these suggestions and post details. as it got working with WeaveNet, now not focusing with flannel.